# What is the difference between brief and detail?

Tags: grammar, difference, antonyms

Are they both antonyms?

While doing my exam

there was written in the question paper
that 'answer the following question in breif'

and 'answer the following question in detail'

the brief one were of 2 marks

and detailed were of 4 marks.

does brief mean short

and detailed mean long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as phrases these two are antonyms and you understood them correctly:

From the Oxford Dictionary:

[in brief](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_brief)

> "In a few words; in short."

[in detail](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_detail)

> "As regards every feature or aspect; fully."

Comment: okay. but this is what confuses me https://wikidiff.com/brief/detail 

Comment: I see. But there is a difference to their meanings as words and as phrases. You want to look at the phrases "in brief" and "in detail" rather than just the words "brief" and "detail".

Comment: what's phrases?

Comment: sorry but I'm not a native speaker

Comment: A phrase is a small group of two or more words. One word can have a meaning by itself and that same word in a phrase can have a new meaning. Just like "detail" (a word) has one meaning and "in detail" (a phrase) has its own meaning.

Comment: okay. now I get. in this phrase 'in brief' and 'in detail' they are antonyms. But what about the one in that link?

Comment: they sound quite like synonyms to me

Comment: Even as words, their definitions are closer to being antonyms. Detail is specific. Brief is general.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75983/discussion-between-jay-a-little-and-user16574).